# Validate registration form with alert

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm building a registration page, which requires username,email,password,confirm password, and agree to the terms, but I'm confused of the way I'm gonna handle inner and inner if statements to show a message if anything typed wrong.

Here is a scenario, I'm saying username textfield should be between 4 and 8 length,and if not show an alert with that details.i don't want to say to the user there is an error and he doesn't know what is it about.like if typed wrong email syntax show an alert to say write a valid email.

I just need a logic to start with of how to handle multiple verification and show detailed message, my current code only shows that there is an error but not detailed.

Here is my code:

```
if (self.UsernameTextfield.text.length >= 4 && self.UsernameTextfield.text.length <= 8 &&
        [Helper validateEmail:self.EmailTextField.text] &&
        [Helper validatePassword:self.PasswordTextfield.text] && [self.PasswordTextfield.text isEqualToString:self.ConfirmTextfield.text] && (self.agreedInPage == YES) ) {
// completed registration
}else {
// something wrong show a general error

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make one method to Check Validation of registration.

```
func RagistationValidation()->Bool
    {
           if txt_Name.text!.isEmpty
           {
            self.alertWithMessaage("Please enter name.")
            return false
           }
           else if txt_Email.text!.isEmpty
           {
            self.alertWithMessaage("Please enter emailid.")
            return false
           }
           else if txt_password.text!.isEmpty
           {
            self.alertWithMessaage("Please enter password.")
            return false
           }
           else if txt_comfirmPwd.text!.isEmpty
           {
            self.alertWithMessaage("Please enter confirm password.")
            return false
           }
           else if txt_Country.text!.isEmpty
           {
            self.alertWithMessaage("Please enter city.")
            return false
           }
           else if txt_City.text!.isEmpty
           {
              self.alertWithMessaage("Select country.")
              return false

           }
           else
           {

                if !Validation.isValidEmail(txt_Email.text!)
                {
                    self.alertWithMessaage("Please enter valid emailid.")
                    return false
                }
                else if !Validation.isPwdLenth(txt_password.text!, confirmPassword: txt_comfirmPwd.text!)
                {
                    self.alertWithMessaage("Your password must have atleast 7 digit.")
                    return false
                }
                else if !Validation.isPasswordSame(txt_password.text!, confirmPassword: txt_comfirmPwd.text!)
                {
                    self.alertWithMessaage("Your password dosen't match.")
                    return false
                }
                else
                {
                    return true
                }

           } 
    }
```

Now Checking validation,

```
   if self.RagistationValidation()
    {
       // completed registration, Calling Service here.
    }
```

Comment: He asked for obj-c and you answered in swift!!

Comment: yes, He understand and Convert in to Objective C, it's Simple.